# ¿Cómo pasar una propiedad en un array de divs en ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un array de componentes en ReactJS y los estoy recorriendo con una función `map`, lo que quisiera es que, en el recorrido se enviara a cada uno de los componentes una propiedad.

Mi código luce así:

```
 <div>
   <StepWizard transitions={custom} >
       {props.steps.map((step, inde) => {
           return (step)
       })}
    </StepWizard>

 </div>
```

En `return (step)` quiero enviar una propiedad a ese componente step que se está renderizando, normalmente haría algo así `<Step propiedad="lo que sea"/>` ¿Cómo puedo enviar una propiedad ahí en map?

Comment: porque se utiliza el return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que step es un componente de React, puedes usar `React.cloneElement`:

```
<div>
   <StepWizard transitions={custom} >
       {props.steps.map((step, inde) => {
           return React.cloneElement(step, { foo: "bar" }); 
       })}
    </StepWizard>

 </div>
```

Citando la [documentación oficial](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

> Clona y retorna un elemento React usando element como punto de partida. El elemento resultante tendrá los props del elemento original con los nuevos props combinados superficialmente. Los nuevos hijos reemplazarán los hijos existentes. key y ref del elemento original serán preservados.

Esto significa que así recibirías dentro de step:

```
function Step({ foo }) {
 console.log(foo); // bar
 return null;
}
```

Comment: por que se usa el return ? no seria renderizar y ya?

Answer (score 2):

Solo expresa el componente `<Step />` con notacion JSX y no olvides asignar una propiedad `key` para que React pueda realizar el renderizado eficientemente.

```
 <div>
   <StepWizard transitions={custom} >
       {props.steps.map((step, inde) => {
           return (<Step prop={props.property} key={somekey} />)
       })}
    </StepWizard>

 </div>
```

Comment: porque utilizas el return?

Comment: @x-rw porque el método `map` retorna un arreglo de elementos, donde cada elemento es retornado de una función que se le pasa como argumento.

Comment: no me di cuenta que era map, bien